# How to build a knowledge base?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm building a project which is to give some relevant information when a user asks for about some specific place or a product.I'm currently doing this using JAVA and MySQL.
Here I need to maintain a knowledge base to keep FAQs and recent searches and so on.

I'm totally new to knowledge bases and I couldn't find a way to start this.Is there any tutorial to follow regarding this or any freely available knowledge bases which I can use in my project?If there is any such knowledge bases,will it be possible for me to connect it with my project?

I'm very much thankful if anyone can guide me in building a knowledge base.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I use Confluence which is not free but costs $10 for up to 10 users. It is a professional wiki and it is worth the time you will same to buy it.

Comment: The $10 for the starter license even goes to charity... how cool is that? Good guy Atlassian says 'It's okay, we make enough money off JIRA'.

Comment: @corsiKa I thought they make money from people who want 11 users ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaWiki it is free, the same is used by Wikipedia also. You can use Share Point also but it needs MSSQL database that you need to purchase.